How to auto import missing dependence when saving typescript on VScode?
When editing GoLang files, VScode can automatically importing missing dependence on save. How to make it works on Typescript files?

how is it going to automatically resolve ambiguities? or do you want to be prompted? also, aren't there already code actions to fix missing imports?
